# Google Cloud Storage "invalid upload request" error. Bad request

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have been uploading files to google cloud storage from my node js server for quite a long time now. But sometimes the upload fails. Error message returned is something like:

```
{
    reason:"badRequest", 
    code: 400,
    message: "Invalid upload request"
}
```

It happens randomly, means once in around 25-30 days for some time and then is resolved automatically.
It's kind of weird and searching for it didn't give any solution or the reason.

The upload request is sent for two files in parallel having exactly the same data.
one was uploaded successfully and other failed.

code used:

```
const file = bucket.file(`data/${id}/${version}/abc.json`);
const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(dataToUpload));
file.save(dataBuffer, storageConfig)
    .then(() => callback(null, true))
    .catch(err => callback(err, null));
```

where storageConfig is

```
{
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "cacheControl": "public, max-age=600, s-maxage=3, no-transform"
}
```

and the second file name which is stored is

```
const file = bucket.file(`data/${id}/latest/abc.json`);
```

I am not able to find any reason for it and unable to handle it.
It crashed my related systems as they require that second file.

Comment: How many uploads requests are you sending? And, when it fails, it fails consistently for some time or just once? I understand that just once. I ask this because is normal to have some failed request, even if 400 stands for "The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error" according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: Hi, I don't have an exact number as it depends on the no. of items selected by the user. But there can be at least 4 and at most 38 upload request. Yes, it fails consistently for some time and is automatically resolved after a few hours and then it works for around a month and fails again. The only message it gives is "Invalid upload request". So, I don't have the exact reason for the failure that I can take care of. I understand that some failure is normal but in our case, even a single failed request is causing problems. It's crashing our page.

Comment: @RubénC. The above no. is for a single request. I.e. in one request, 4 to 38 files can be uploaded for that entity.

Comment: I am with GCP. Open a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/) (if it is possible for you) the next time it happens so we have "fresh" information and access to check what is going on in your project. Otherwise you can create a [private issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new). Let me know when you do it in this last case.

Comment: @RubénC.  Thanks for your response. I will  surely open a support case and let you know in the comment here.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I talked to the guy handling it and we should be able to help you better now. Good luck!

Comment: Hey @SankalpKataria. We are facing a similar issue. were you able to understand the cause of the issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @YatinGera, I got in touch with google cloud support and found that I was using resumable uploads(enabled by default) which do not work well for files smaller than 10 MB(which was my case). So, I added resumable: false to my upload options(several days back). I haven't got any error after that. In case, the error occurs again I will comment here for a further solution(if any) after contacting support.

Comment: @YatinGera, If you've found something that could help me please share. thanks.

Comment: Hi @SankalpKataria! Did `resumable: false`  solved your issue? Our files can grow larger, do you see some solution for this? Thanks in advance for this thread.

Answer (score 8):

Setting `resumable: false` in the upload options solved the same error for me. For example : `bucket.upload(pathToUpload, { destination: bucketPath, resumable: false })`